# What is a better way of creating objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use prototype or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691044/should-i-use-prototype-or-not)
>   [Closures in auto executing functions vs objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231730/closures-in-auto-executing-functions-vs-objects)

So, I'm creating an object in JavaScript, there are two ways of going about this:

```
function car(){
    this.engineOn = false;
    this.startEngine = function(){
        this.engineOn = true;
    }
}
```

OR

```
function car(){
    this.engineOn = false;
}
car.prototype.startEngine = function(){
    this.engineOn = true;
}
```

What is the best way to do this? And are there any benefits or disadvantages to either method?

Comment: I think you intended to have `this.engineOn = false;` in the first one as well.  As it is now the two piece of code are not equivalent as the first does not have a starting value for `engineOn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, prototype is not created with each object, but is created **once** for all objects.