# Which javascript object creation is more efficient?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I understand the recommended manner is Version 2 (below), using prototype.  However, what is the difference between the two versions because not only does Version 1 sometimes beat Version 2 in memory consumption, it also routinely completes in half to a third of the time (according to my tests using Chrome).

**Version 1:**

```
   var C = function() { console.log("new C"); }

   C.f = function(foo) { console.log("function"); }

   var a = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
       a.push(new C());
   }
```

**Version 2:**

```
   var C = function() { console.log("new C"); }

   C.prototype.f = function(foo) { console.log("function"); }

   var a = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
       a.push(new C());
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closures in auto executing functions vs objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231730/closures-in-auto-executing-functions-vs-objects)

Comment: Are you "extending" the object? Or simply creating the object to be used?

Comment: Your scripts are not equivalent. In the first case, `f` is a property of the constructor function `C`, that means the instances you create with `new C()` **do not** have a reference to `f`. In the second one, you assign `f` to `C`'s prototype, from which all instances inherit. You are comparing apples with oranges. It should not make a difference in the performance though... here is a jsPerf testcase: http://jsperf.com/static-vs-prototype

Comment: ACTUAL ANSWER: Depends on the interpreter/compiler.

Comment: @FelixKling: But shouldn't both scripts should run in the same time and memory? Objects in version 1 should still reference C.prototype in the same way as version 2 (and I don't know of any clever tricks to get around it here)

Comment: @FelixKling: it might make a difference, since Version 1 will create an empty object, and Version 2 will create an object with a prototype containing the member `f`.

Comment: @Martijn: In each version, a new instance will inherit from `C.prototype`, no matter which properties it has. If any the difference is marginal and there is not point in comparing these because they do different things. I can also compare the performance of `var a = 0;` and `var a = Math.pow(7,34523462357234623460)` but what is the point?

Comment: @FelixKling: That’s true, of course. I was merely wondering whether the compiler could have optimized that somehow (though I’ve no idea how).

Comment: @Martijn: Maybe, but I don't have an idea how the compilers work either. I ran the test case a couple of time and there is no notable difference.

Comment: @Felix Kling: correct you are. Being that the desired outcome is below, Version 1 does not make sense.
`var c = new C(); c.f('asf');`

Answer (score 1):

version 1 will give the function to your object only, while version 2 will provide the function to all object from the function holding the prototype.

And actually I'm pretty curious to see if any of your `new C();` instanciations in version 1 has access to the C.f method...

Comment: Theoretically yes, through `instance.constructor.f` (my comment was actually not precise enough), but I don't think that this is the desired way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Any performance difference is moot, because the first version doesn't work.

Adding a function as a property to a constructor function doesn't make it a method in the created object.

Answer (score 0):

To test out JavaScript language away from the browser you could use my [Script Scraper](http://www.scriptscraper/answers/felix/felix.html) tool.

[image]

thanks,
Martin.